# Making use of inbuilt namespaces in C#

Tags: .net, namespaces

Scenario:

Assume I want to define my own class.

```
public class Person
{
}
```

I wish to put it in a namespace System.

Note: I have not included the directive, '`using System`' at the top..

```
namespace System
{
    public class Person
    {
        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am mine");
        }
    }
}
```

Though I have not included `using System;` directive at the top, I am still able to access `System.Console.WriteLine` in my method, since my declared namespace is `System`.

How is this possible? how does it go about?

Comment: mscorlib.dll is available automatically. So, even if you don't add "using System;" it is available to your class.

Comment: @shahkalpesh that's not the case.  The only types you can use without a specific 'using' statement are the C# alias types such as int/string/object/etc

Comment: That's not true either, as this works:

global::System.Console.WriteLine("Testing, 1, 2, 3...");

Comment: Note that using directives are to do with namespaces, whereas mscorlib.dll is an assembly. They're very different concepts.

Comment: @Jon: You are right. However System namespace & Console class is part of mscorlib.dll. And that being the base assembly (containing Object), it is available by default. Am I wrong in saying that?

Comment: @Jon: Assuming Drew is right, how is it possible to use int/string (alias) which refer to types such as Int32 in mscorlib.dll but not Console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you declare namespace `Foo.Bar.Baz`, every namespace in that hierarchy (`Foo`, `Foo.Bar` and `Foo.Bar.Baz`) is searched when you reference a type from within that namespace declaration:

```
namespace Foo.Bar.Baz
{
    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // This will search for Foo.Bar.Baz.SomeType,
            // Foo.Bar.SomeType, Foo.SomeType, SomeType,
            // in that order
            SomeType.StaticMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

See section 3.8 of the C# 3.0 language specification for the gory details.

However, I hope you are *not* seriously considering using this as a way to avoid adding using directives. Creating your own types in the System namespace hierarchy is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the using directive inside the same namespace.

If you declare your classes in System then "using System;" is implicit.

However, this is probably not where you should be putting your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have defined your type in the `System` namespace, you have access to all other types defined in the `System` namespace.

Similarly, if you defined your class in `System.Data`, you would have access to `System` and `System.Data` without requiring explicit using statements.

Namespaces may be duplicated across assemblies.

Note that defining your type in the same namespace does not grant you access to internal members of types defined in the same namespace but different assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Anything declared inside a namespace has access to all the other classes in that same namespace (provided you have a reference to the assembly containing that namespace and those classes).

Answer (score 0):

[Namespaces implicitly have public access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2kcy19k(VS.71).aspx) and this is not modifiable.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have declared your class as being part of the namespace and therefore it automatically includes the assembly for it.

In the same way any file within a project namespace doesn't need to declare it as using that project namespace.